Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8E3867A3-8586-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628} failed
I am working on a project on windows 11 and Visual Studio 22, and I have had to revamp many sub and different functions within the program to get things to work, mainly due to things being outdated and unsupported. I have been battling this COM error for a few days now. I receive the error when my project gets to InitializeComponets() in the main windows form of the project. I also receive the error An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8E3867A3-8586-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
I suspected the problem to be with my MSComctLib.dll since the COM class it gives me goes to mscomctl.StatusBar. I have gone through all of the steps from other post with a similar issue. I have tried to run in both x64 and x86. I have unchecked running in 32 Bit. I have made sure the key is registered in both 64 and 32. I have tried to get rid of the Statusbar element in my form, but the project wouldn't build. When I go to open my form I get
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Instances of this error (1)  
 
1.   Hide Call Stack 
 
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)  


I have tried to register and fix all of the .dll I am using but have not made anything work. I have another project with the same .dll so I know it can't be an issue with the .dll since the do work. I have also compared codes and the line sI have for Statusbar are the same for both projects.

You forgot to mention the .NET version you're targeting in the Projects you're referring to. In case one of them is .NET 5+, then replace the StatuBar with a StatusStrip (well, replace it everywhere, if possible). Same goes for MainMenu / MenuStrip

I am running on .NET v8. But would I be able to simply change that in the code, because some of the instances are within the autogenerated code from WINFORMS?

Support for SatusBar / MainMenu / DataGrid (and a few other) has been removed in .NET. You have some manual work to do

Okay, so I just check and I have v8 installed on my computer but the program is actually set to v4.8. Would it be best to upgrade to a more recent version or should I try to get v4.8 to work @Jimi ?

That's up to you. Moving to .NET is probably better than hanging on .NET Framework, and replacing a StatusBar is not that complicated. Of course, I don't know how much code you have behind that thing, so the testing stuff may take some time. If you don't have that time, then stick to .NET Framework 4.8. Install the Developer Pack, via Visual Studio or download it directly (though it's kind of weird you don't have it already installed. Make sure to verify what .NET version you're actually targeting)

.NET Framework is not likely to have any more major updates, but it's also likely to continue to be supported for a long time, longer than any version of the newer Core-derived .NET.  Core-derived .NET is undergoing active development, but even the "LTS" versions are only supported for ~3 years.

Thank you both for the advice. The program is quite large so it would most likely take me a very long time to do that much updating so I will stick with the v4.8.
